# Why is back button closing activity instead of reversing fragment transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The main activity opens the main_fragment with this transaction:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_main_container, new MainFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

Then I replace that fragment with another one like this:

```
// method to handle Conversions button click
public void addConversionsFragment (View v) {
    // replace the main fragment with the conversion fragment
    UnitConversionFragment newFragment = new UnitConversionFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_main_container, newFragment);
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit(); 
}
```

Originally, I was using `support.v4.app.fragment`, and everything was working as expected (back button in the second fragment would pop that one out and return to the `MainFragment`.  But then I decided to implement a `PreferenceFragment` elsewhere, which the support library didn't seem to like.  So I converted the whole project to the regular `app.fragment` by deleting all the support imports, replacing with the regular imports, then editing all the `getSupportFragmentManager()` with `getFragmentManager()`, etc.

Good news is the`PreferenceFragment` works well, however any time I hit the back button in a fragment, it closes the hosting activity rather than reversing the transaction.

I did many searches and it seems that I am implementing the code correctly, but it is just not responding as I am expecting.  Is there more involved in converting away from the support library?  Or am I missing something else obvious?  I saw a lot of answers out there overriding the `onBackPressed()`, but I really don't want to do that.

Is there some fundamental difference between the v4 support library and the regular library that requires me to handle the fragment transactions differently?

Comment: can you show your onBackPressed() method here

Comment: I never did any kind of override for onBackPressed().

Comment: try to follow answer provided by S.D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preference Fragment has a bit of extra logic to handle hierarchical preferences. You can configure it to launch sub fragment screens, and navigate back, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14708151/1531054).

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="Sub Preferences"
        android:fragment="com.example.SettingsDemo.SubPrefFragment"/>
```

For normal fragments , fragment back-stack pops first before reaching Activity back stack. This is what is documented.

The code in both `android.app.Activity` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` is exactly same:

```
 /**
 * Take care of popping the fragment back stack or finishing the activity
 * as appropriate.
 */
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

The only reason it is not happening as expected is that something else consumes "back press", this may happen when there are 3 levels of components:

1. The `Activity` is inside an `ActivityGroup`.
2. `Fragment` is inside another `Fragment`. (for this, there are some bugs with v4 fragments).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The issue I am having is with any/all of my fragments, not just the PreferenceFragment.

Comment: @user3127074  added more info to answer.

Comment: I think you are right, but I am not sure what was consuming the back press.  At the moment, I have the app working, but I am not sure why.  When I created the project, eclipse automatically

Comment: When I created the project, eclipse automatically extended the ActionBarActivity (appcompat_v7 library) and I just went with it.  My min sdk is 11, so in my understanding, I should not need to use the compatability library.  I decided to try removing all reference to that library (changed extends ActionBarActivity to extends Activity).

In doing so, I found two instances of getSupportFragmentManager() that I missed when I was taking out the v4 support library.  So I fixed those also, and now it works.  My guess is my issue had to do with those support library references and not appcompat lib.